# Proving the Lebesgue outer measure of a set is > 0

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I've probably missed something really simple but I can't seem to find a straightforward proof that the Lebesgue outer measure of a set is > 0, starting from the following definitions:

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be the set of all open intervals, and define $\mu_0 : \mathcal{S} \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ by $\mu_0( (a, b) ) = b - a$.

Then define $\mu^*(E) = inf \{ \sum \mu_0 (A_i) | E \subseteq \cup A_i, A_i \in \mathcal{S} \} $

How can I show that $\mu^* ((0, 1)) = 1$ or $\mu^* ([0,1]) = 1$ for example? I struggled to even prove they were $ > 0$, when I tried the following proof by contradiction:

Suppose $\mu^*([0, 1]) = 0$. Then $\forall \epsilon > 0$, we can find $A_i \in \mathcal{S}$ such that $ [0,1] \subseteq \cup A_i$, and $\sum \mu_0(A_i) < \epsilon$. Then by compactness of $[0,1]$, we can find a finite subcover from these $A_i$'s. At this point I was fairly convinced that if you were careful enough you could complete this proof to find a contradiction; by for instance taking a union of sufficient $A_i$ to cover a large enough part of the interval to have $\mu_0$ of the sum be $> \epsilon$, but this seemed like a lot of work for what felt like it should be much more straightforward.

Could anyone provide a simple proof of the above, and point out if I've made any mistakes in my reasoning?

Comment: For $[0,1]$, you can use compactness to reduce it to the case where we have finitely many open intervals covering it. Then you can use induction. For $(0,1)$, it contains $[\epsilon,1-\epsilon]$, so we can reduce it to the previous case.

Comment: Thanks! I tried this out and I think everything makes sense with this approach, will eventually edit the post with this sketched out more fully as the solution if nobody provides a more elementary proof.